# Node JS + DIME - sending binary data in POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, binary-data

There's a file 1740 bytes long, it's contents is read to a Buffer `res`. `res.length` is 1740 and `res.toString('binary', 0, res.length).length` is also 1740.

I send a POST request using `request` lib

```
 request.post({
    url: endpoint,
    headers: headers,
    body: res.toString('binary', 0, res.length)
}, callback);
```

The request goes to a gSOAP server. Through hours of debugging on the server I send request to, we found the following: the request that comes to the server is **1753** bytes long and some characters are converted. In particular, hex `B7` becomes `C2 B7`, so it's converted as described here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b7/index.htm

I tried setting `encoding: 'binary'` and `encoding: null` to request params, same result (with `encoding : null` I only get the error message as a buffer, but that's all).

I tried using `https` library and piping a strean into the request, same result.

Best regards, Alexander

**EDIT**

At the moment, I found a workaround with cURL, just sending a request from cli with `--data-binary "@file_to_which_i_dumped_the_request"'` does the thing. But the app and the nodejs server itself is shipped within an installer, so we'd have to install cURL on users' machines too which is... acceptable, but is not the best option.

So is there  way to send a binary POST body with nodejs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `binary` string encoding: it has been deprecated ([see here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer)) and it only makes sense if "the other side" will decode it back to a buffer.

Just use the buffer directly:

```
request.post({
  url     : endpoint,
  headers : headers,
  body    : res
}, callback);
```

Comment: Hey Robert, thanks for your response, but I've tried to send the ``Buffer`` object, the DIME responded with the same error.

Comment: @strrife so the amount of data received on the server is more than 1740 bytes too in that case?

Comment: @strrife sending a buffer as body will prevent Node from doing any processing on the data (it's similar to `--data-binary`). If it doesn't work, I wonder if there's not perhaps another issue that's causing your problems (perhaps missing/incorrect headers?)

Comment: @strrife how are you reading the file into Node? Just a plain `fs.readFile()` or `fs.readFileSync()` I presume?

Comment: The headers are fine, to form a cURL requests I use the same headers. Maybe node itself adds some extra headers?

Comment: @strrife `request.debug = true` will make `request` log debugging data (including headers).

Comment: Don't you try just update request.js? It maybe fixed in new version of package